# Salt shows K/V in pillar.items but don't show specific key

Tags: salt-stack

I'm a novice in this and have some problems with using salt.

I want to target some monions, using pillar data

1. I've added K\V on Consul [testrun:run] for the node
2. I tried to view pillar.items in CLI and here is what I see

   ```
   # salt node-306 pillar.items
   node-306:
       ----------
       group:
           cpc
       region:
           ru
       sname:
           ru-qa-bat3
       team:
           qa
       testrun:
           run
   ```
3. But when I'm trying to get specific Key, I see this:

   ```
   # salt node-306 pillar.item testrun
   node-306:
       ----------
       testrun:
   ```

What I did wrong? What to check? Can't understand why salt shows it and at the same time doesn't

**UPD:**
After applying salt node-306 saltutil.refresh_pillar

```
 #salt node-306 saltutil.refresh_pillar
node-306:
    True
# salt node-306 pillar.item testrun
node-306:
    ----------
    testrun:
        run
# salt -C "I@testrun:run" pillar.item sname
node-306:
    Minion did not return. [No response]
ERROR: Minions returned with non-zero exit code
```

Comment: Try running `salt node-306 saltutil.refresh_pillar` and then run your `pillar.item` command. I just tested this using a regular pillar value and it worked correctly. If the Consul pillar isn't returning the `testrun` key value, then there's a bug.

Comment: Thanks man! That helped. But right after that I got another problem. Tried to target this minion using compound and got error - updated question

Comment: Which OS is node-306 running?

Comment: Windows 8.1 Pro

Answer (score 0):

Per my first comment, try running `salt node-306 saltutil.refresh_pillar`.

Then for your second issue, sometimes Windows is a bit slow. Try telling the Salt cli to wait a few more seconds for a response from the minion:

`salt -C "I@testrun:run" pillar.item sname -t 20`

Comment: This did'nt help. Don't know why. If I use pillar.item <item> - it's ok
If I use compount targeting, using new K\V item - ERROR: Minions returned with non-zero exit code